# problema com try e except em um programa simples python

Tags: python

```
def questao3():
    while True:
        try:
            nome_produto = input('Digite o nome do produto: ')
            preco = float(input('Digite o preco desse produto: '))
            while preco <=0 or preco > 100:
                raise ValueError
            quantidade = int(input('Digite a quantidade do produto: '))
            while quantidade < 0 or quantidade > 1000:
                raise ValueError
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Encerrando o programa...')
            return -1
        except ValueError:
            print('valor invalido, o preco deve ser um valor maior q 0 e menor que 100.')
            print('a quantidade deve ser um inteiro entre 0 e 1000')
        else:
            lista = [nome_produto, preco, quantidade]
            return lista
print(questao3())
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço p imprimir uma mensagem diferente pra cada caso, caso a resposta não possa ser convertida pra float(no preço) e não possa ser convertida pra int(na quantidade). ambos se encaixam no ValueError, mas n to sabendo imprimir uma mensagem pra cada. Gostaria de saber tb como faço pro programa insistir na mesma pergunta ate que a resposta seja a correta (ao inves de reiniciar o programa) desde já agradeço

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para obter o resultado desejado podemos utilizar um tratamento de erro específico para cada input da seguinte forma:

```
    def questao3():
    try:
        nome_produto = input('Digite o nome do produto: ')

        while True:
            preco = float(input('Digite o preco desse produto: '))
            if preco <= 0 or preco > 100:
                print('valor invalido, o preco deve ser um valor maior q 0 e menor que 100.')
            else:
                break

        while True:
            quantidade = int(input('Digite a quantidade do produto: '))
            if quantidade < 0 or quantidade > 1000:
                print('a quantidade deve ser um inteiro entre 0 e 1000')
            else:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Encerrando o programa...')
        return -1
    else:
        lista = [nome_produto, preco, quantidade]
        return lista

print(questao3())
```

Dessa forma o usuário ficará preso em cada entrada até que digite um valor valido e, caso erre receberá a mensagem de erro definida.

Comment: você é um anjo!! mt obrigado, me ajudou muito

Comment: Não foi nada! Caso precise de mais alguma coisa pode contar comigo

Comment: em breve vou precisar mesmo kkk mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: @matheussantos Só um detalhe: lançar uma exceção (com `raise`) dentro de um bloco `try`, só para forçar que caia no `except`, é um uso torto de exceções. Nesse caso, o mais simples é colocar a mensagem de erro no `if` e pronto. Até porque são situações diferentes: se cair no `except` é porque não foi digitado um número, e se cai no `if` é porque foi digitado um número mas ele não está no intervalo correto. Outro detalhe é que o `continue` ali no primeiro `while` é redundante e pode ser removido. Sugestão: https://ideone.com/mFzbAQ - ou ainda: https://ideone.com/6BWhX4

Comment: Obrigado pelo adendo, vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: queria saber pq teve tanto voto negativo nessa pergunta.. fiz algo de errado ????